# Avoid creation of _id column in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I'm using android.persistence.room to create a database. I have an intermediate table in which rows are identified with the PK's of two other tables, so there's no need for an id column (i'm not using a cursor). There is no id field in my class, room doesn't complain about it. And i've added a migration in which i create a new table without id column; copy existing data and renaming it (the typical drop column approach in sqlite), still the id column is there.

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipe_ingredients",
        foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(entity =
                    Recipe.class,
                    parentColumns = "id",
                    childColumns = "recipe",
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
            @ForeignKey(entity =
                    Ingredient.class,
                    parentColumns = "id",
                    childColumns = "ingredient",
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.RESTRICT)
        },
        primaryKeys = {"recipe", "ingredient"})
public class RecipeIngredient {

//region members
    @ColumnInfo(name = "recipe")
private int mReceptId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ingredient")
private int mIngredientId;
    @Embedded
private Ingredient mIngredient;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "amount")
private double amount;
    @Ignore
private int mNumberOfRecipeIdChanges;
    @Ignore
private int mNumberOfIngredientIdChanges;
//endregion
```

and my migration

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Create the new table
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredients_new " +
                "(recipe INTEGER NOT NULL, ingredient INTEGER NOT NULL," + 
                "  amount REAL NOT NULL," +
                " PRIMARY KEY(recipe, ingredient), " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(recipe) REFERENCES recipes(id)" +
                " ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE ," +
                " FOREIGN KEY(ingredient) REFERENCES ingredients(id) " +
                "ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT )" );
        // Copy the data
        database.execSQL(
                "INSERT INTO recipe_ingredientes_new (recipe, "+ 
                 " ingredient, amount)" +
                        " SELECT  recipe, ingredient, amount FROM 
recipe_ingredients");
        // Remove the old table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE recipe_ingredients");
        // Change the table name to the correct one
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE recipe_ingredients_new RENAME TO 
 recipe_ingredients");

    }
};
```

Comment: Your migration won't run properly, due to typos (`recipe_ingredients_new` versus `recipe_ingredientes_nieuw`). Beyond that, how have you determined that "still the id column is there"?

Comment: the typo slipped in upon translation for here. I pulled a copy of the database from the device file explorer and took a peek with DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: recipe_ingredientes_nieuw typo adjusted

Comment: Take a look at the schemas used by Room. That will be in your generated Java code for your database, plus in the schema JSON if you're saving it via Gradle.

Comment: _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    `recept_ingredienten` (`recept` INTEGER NOT NULL, `ingredient` 
     INTEGER NOT NULL, `hoeveelheid` REAL NOT NULL, `id` 
    INTEGER, `naam` TEXT, `eenheid` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`recept`, 
    `ingredient`), FOREIGN KEY(`recept`) REFERENCES `recepten`(`id`) 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE , FOREIGN 
    KEY(`ingredient`) REFERENCES `ingredienten`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO 
    ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT )");

Comment: it's there the id column, could this be with the @Embedded annotation of the ingredient

Comment: If `Ingredient` has an `id` column, then yes.

Comment: ingredient indeed has an id column.Then the created id column in the recipe_ingredient table is the PK of the ingredient, would have noticed sooner if it wouldn't have been 0 for each row...

Comment: Ditching the @Embedded annotation. And i'll make a pojo to get the info i want.